# UPS Outh Rating API return Invalid Authentication Information

Tags: oauth-2.0, integration, ups

I facing issue in UPS Rating API integration.

My request body is:

```
{
    "RateRequest": {
        "shipper": {
            "address": {
                "postal_code": "12345",
                "country_code": "US"
            }
        },
        "shipTo": {
            "address": {
                "postal_code": "54321",
                "country_code": "US"
            }
        },
        "shipment": {
            "package": {
                "dimensions": {
                    "unit_of_measurement": "IN",
                    "length": "10",
                    "width": "6",
                    "height": "4"
                },
                "weight": {
                    "unit_of_measurement": "LBS",
                    "weight": "1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

URL - https://wwwcie.ups.com/api/rating/v1/Rate?additionalinfo=string

and passing access token in header but it always returns

```
{
"response": {
"errors": [
{
"code": "250002",
"message": "Invalid Authentication Information."
}
]
}
}
```

Comment: You should mark your answer as the correct one so people know that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer.
I didn't add Rating API permission to my app. That was the issue.
After adding, it's working fine.

To add the Rating API, login to your developer account and go to your Apps page at

https://developer.ups.com/apps?loc=en_US

Then edit your app and add the Rating API.

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to add API permissions in the 'App/Edit App Add Products' section.
```

Comment: I'm voting to delete this, because it's the same as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76135075/7758804). Don't add **thank you**, or **confirmation** answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) from quality contributions, you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/35049024)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else getting this API error code and unresolved by correcting/verifying permissions issues, note that header values are case-sensitive: a lowercase `bearer <token>` will produce error 250002 from UPS, whereas `Bearer <token>` should succeed if all else is good to go.